# How to marshall struct defined from macros in C header?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, vulkan

I have NO idea hot to marshall the next part of [Vulkan API header file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/40c8b0a/ndk/platforms/android-24/include/vulkan/vulkan.h) for C# use:

```
#define VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(object) typedef struct object##_T* object;
...
VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(VkInstance)
```

I need to use in this method later:

```
VKAPI_ATTR VkResult VKAPI_CALL vkCreateInstance(
    const VkInstanceCreateInfo*  pCreateInfo,
    const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator,
    VkInstance*                  pInstance
);
```

Pointer to `vkInstance`, okay. But, what is this magic stuff: `typedef struct object##_T* object;` in macros-style (preprocessor)?

Comment: I just create a structure in C# making sure the type sizes are the same as c++.  No Marshal is required.

Comment: VkInstance, as well all other non dispatchable Vulkan handles, is (are) just  pointer to a generic struct.

Comment: If you're interested, there's a few of us have already written C# bindings for Vulkan - https://github.com/FacticiusVir/SharpVk/blob/master/SharpVk/SharpVk/Interop/Handles.cs#L404

Comment: @FacticiusVir thanks :) great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ## is the concatenate operator in the C++ pre-processor - so in the above example

```
#define VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(object) typedef struct object##_T* object;
VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(VkInstance)
```

would expand out to

```
typedef struct VkInstance_T* VkInstance;
```

Comment: I see, but how can I inspect which is `VkInstance` is? I'm trying to jump into its definition, but can't go more, than `VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(VkInstance)`, which references to the macros? How to marshal it? Is it an empty struct? Thanks

Comment: It is a pointer to a struct. Nothing else. You may interpret  VK_DEFINE_HANDLE as a sort of `typedef void* VkInstance;` , + or - less what @PaulIF wrote above.

Comment: Try googling VkInsatnce - this is top of the list : https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkInstance.html

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it seems like you want to know the contents of the `VkInstance` handle, so that you can save it to disk or transmit it over the network.

**It's not possible**. Not only are the actual contents of `VkInstance` (as well as any other Vulkan handle) not specified, they *cannot* be specified at compile time, because their contents *are completely dependent on the Vulkan implementation your program happens to run with* (For example, the contents of Nvidia's `VkInstance` surely will not match AMD's `VkInstance`, or Intel's).

Even if you knew the struct layout somehow, it wouldn't be possible simply save it, because I can guarantee you that it will contain a reference to a runtime resource that simply cannot be saved, such as a socket or a driver resource handle.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot :) btw, I have succeeded in Vulkan instance creation via C#, proof: https://s17.postimg.org/uzmt2tv5r/i168_cimgpsh_orig.png

Comment: @MatthewTipton Well, yes, that's possible, because the Vulkan implementation is allocating the `VkInstance` for you. You don't need to know what it contains, you just need a handle to use with Vulkan functions.